# JavaScript GET Request Webpage image in Stream

Tags: javascript, rest, loops, stream, jpeg

I have a url that has a new jpeg  on it everytime you visit the page . I would like to use my javascript get constantly send get statements to that page and retrieve the image to display it on my webpage in as "stream" of images in a container one after the other  . Currently I can only get the first image when I run the function. I am new to JavaScript.

```
    isLive=true;
    let imageurl = SERVICE_URL;
    var ajaxImage = document.getElementById("liveImg");
      do {

            xhttp.open("GET",imageurl, true);
            xhttp.send();
            ajaxImage.src = imageurl;

          }
          while (isLive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use infinite loops in javascript to do ajax like this because it would send many request without any limit crashing the browser and yes the server as well if there are many clients

What you need instead is a [timer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) that would tick, say every 5 seconds changing the image

```
isLive=true;
let imageurl = SERVICE_URL;
var ajaxImage = document.getElementById("liveImg");
var timerKey = 0;

function Imgchanger{
    //incase you want to stop it just assign isLive=false somewhere
    if(!isLive){
        clearInterval(timerKey);
    }

    xhttp.open("GET",imageurl, true);
    xhttp.send();
    ajaxImage.src = imageurl;
}

timerKey  = setInterval(imgchanger, 5000); //5 seconds
```